# Endless loop query: select WHERE IN (select distinct ...)

Tags: mysql

I am trying to figure out if anyone else in my woltlab forum has used the same `userAgent` (software specs) as "noname". There are thousands of entries, and many are multiple times in the table. So I'm using `DISTINCT` to list all userAgents of noname. This by itself works fine. But I want to check for entries from other users with the same userAgent.

```
SELECT * FROM db_123456.wcf1_user_iplog
 WHERE userAgent IN 
    (SELECT DISTINCT(userAgent)
        FROM db_123456.wcf1_user_iplog 
        WHERE username = "noname"
    )
 AND username != "noname";
```

this however results in an endless loop. At least I think it is one, because 50k entries will probably not result in more than 120 seconds of execution.
I used: MySQL Workbench and phpMyAdmin.

Why does this not terminate?

What can I do?

Comment: no the whole table has 50k rows, the inner select delivers correctly only 9 rows. I should be able to search for these 9 userAgents in my table, shouldnt I ??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MySQL often optimizes `WHERE IN` poorly, and tends to do better with `JOIN`.

```
SELECT a.*
FROM db_123456.wcf1_user_iplog AS a
JOIN (SELECT DISTINCT userAgent
      FROM db_123456.wcf1_user_iplog
      WHERE username = "noname") AS b
ON a.userAgent = b.userAgent
AND a.username != "noname"
```

BTW, `DISTINCT` isn't a function, there's no need to put parentheses around the column name.

Answer (score 0):

Unless the query optimizer converts your query to a join (it should, but mysql can be dense), the inner query creates a huge temporary table and depending on resources available may deal with it poorly... and usually does.

You can help mysql by coding an equivalent query expressed as a join:

```
SELECT DISTINCT t.*
FROM db_123456.wcf1_user_iplog t
JOIN db_123456.wcf1_user_iplog t2
  ON t2.userAgent = t.userAgent
  AND username = 'noname'
WHERE username != 'noname'
```

Ensure there's an index on `userAgent` for best performance.

This query may seem similar to Barmar's, but I believe this will perform better, due to:

- there being no subquery
- the username condition being pushed into the join condition (which is evaluated during the join, not on the result of the join
- the distinct operator being at the top level